# Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email fails with invalid email address when using Target Object Id

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage

I have a custom object that allows my users to create series of emails to their clients. I have a scheduled Apex job running hourly that scans for emails that are schedule to go out, creates the EmailMessages and sends them out.
I have fields for recipient lists and options to use the Contact as Target Object id.

This setup has been working for 5 years, and suddenly stopped working for emails that have a target object id, but no additional recipents. Has something changed in the new release?

Here's how  I set up the Email Message:

```
public static Messaging.SingleEmailMessage createMessage(Email__c e){
    List<String> recipients = e.Email_List__c.split(',');
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    msg.setUseSignature(False);
    msg.setTemplateId((Id)e.Email_Template_ID__c);
    msg.setSaveAsActivity(true);
    if(!recipients.isEmpty()) msg.setToAddresses(recipients);
    if(e.Send_to_Contact__c){
        msg.setTargetObjectId(e.Contact__c);
        msg.setWhatId(e.Trip__c);
    }
    else{
        msg.setTargetObjectId(e.TargetObjectForEmail__c);
        System.debug('target object id:'+e.TargetObjectForEmail__c);
    }
    if(e.From_Triggering_User__c == True){
        msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(ScheduleEmails.CurrentUserOWA);
    }
    else if(e.OrgWideEmail__c != ''){
        msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId((Id)e.OrgWideEmail__c);
    }
    System.debug('adding message. The target object id is:'+msg.getTargetObjectId());
    return msg;
}
```

And here's how I send them:

```
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToSend, false);
            Integer numResults = results.size();
            String errorMessage;
            System.StatusCode statusCode;
            //loop through results
            for(Integer i = 0; i < numResults; i++){
                //get the result and email object
                Messaging.SendEmailResult r = results.get(i);
                Email__c e = preparedEmails.get(i);
                if (r.isSuccess()) {
                    e.Sent_Date__c = datetime.now();
                    sentEmails.add(e);
                }
                else{
                    statusCode = r.getErrors()[0].getStatusCode();
                    errorMessage = '';
                    for(Messaging.SendEmailError error:r.getErrors()){
                     errorMessage += error .getMessage() + '\r\n';
                    }
                    errorMessageReport += '\r\n' + errorMessage + '\r\nLink: ' +
                    System.Url.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()  + '/' + e.id
                    + '\r\nThe recipient list: ' + e.Email_List__c;
                }
            }
```

The error is: 
`Invalid to address :`

I have triple checked that the contacts have valid email addresses.

Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: As per Salesforce docs: Do not specify the IDs of records that have the Email Opt Out option selected. Is there any record which have that option selected?

Comment: Thanks for having a look @CloudConnect, but no, these contacts haven't opted out.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this, here's what happened.

```
List<String> recipients = e.Email_List__c.split(',');
```

The line above created a list with one empty string. So even though I checked if the list was empty before setting the toAddresses to it here:

```
if(!recipients.isEmpty()) msg.setToAddresses(recipients);
```

it was adding one empty email address.

I updated it to the following:

```
if(!String.isEmpty(e.Email_List__c)){
        List<String> recipients = e.Email_List__c.split(',');
        msg.setToAddresses(recipients);
}
```

and that solved the issue.

Comment: Your issue is abit similar to mine. Have you dealt with what happens when you send to emails no longer existing? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/310543/38191