# How to use Messaging.SingleEmailMessage to force stop sending emails to email addresses that no longer exist / email server problem

Tags: apex, visualforce, email, singleemailmessage, recursion

So I have created a button on a Visualforce page to call the controller to send an email like so. It works perfectly for valid emails but little did I know the hell that came when I sending it to invalid emails.

When I mean invalid emails here are some I found on the Email logs:

```
1) 421 4.4.0 [internal] no mail servers for this domain could be reached at this time
2) 421 Too many concurrent SMTP connections; please try again later.
3) 451 4.4.2 [internal] no MAIL FROM response
4) 451 4.4.2 [internal] send BODY failed
5) 451 4.7.0 Temporary server error. Please try again later. PRX5 NextHop: substrate-int.office.com. RemoteHost: HKAPR04CA0009. Network Error: 10054 [HK2APC01FT038.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com]
6) 451 DT:SPM 163 mx1,M8CowABXCgG6kddeP6XKDQ--.23718S3 1591185887, please try again 15min later
7) 451 Temporarily unable to process your email. Please try again later.
8) 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
9) 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system resources (TSTE) [TYAPR04MB2381.apcprd04.prod.outlook.com] [HK2PR02CA0201.apcprd02.prod.outlook.com] [HK2APC01FT028.eop-APC01.prod.protection.outlook.com]
10) 452 4.7.1 <email>: Recipient address rejected: Users Mailbox Full
11) 454 4.4.4 [internal] no MX or A for domain
12) 550 5.5.0 Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable (S2017062302). [CY1NAM02FT035.eop-nam02.prod.protection.outlook.com]
13) 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try\r\n550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or\r\n550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at\r\n550 5.1.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=NoSuchUser nu3si2097233pjb.85 - gsmtp
14) 554 5.4.7 [internal] exceeded max time without delivery
```

See this code:

```
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

for (xxx){
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage ();
    email.setTemplateId(emailTemplates[0].Id);
    email.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    email.setToAddresses(addresses);
    emails.add(email);
}

List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
//Catch invalid emails and expose to VF page
for(Messaging.SendEmailResult ser : results){
    if (ser.isSuccess()) {
        Apexpages.addMessage(new apexpages.message(Apexpages.Severity.Info, ser + ' '));
    }  else {             
        for(Messaging.SendEmailError err : ser.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
            System.debug('fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
            Apexpages.addMessage(new apexpages.message(Apexpages.Severity.Error, 'Status Code: ' + err.getStatusCode() + ' Message: ' + err.getMessage() + ' Field Affected: ' + err.getFields() ));
        }
    }
}
```

Some how when I press the button to Email. It spits out the success toast message and the Developer console will spit out a debug log without any error every 6 seconds :

[image: Invalid Email Recurring Loop]

Debug Logs if I click into 1 of them:

```
46.0 APEX_CODE,FINE;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,FINEST;DB,FINEST;NBA,NONE;SYSTEM,FINE;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,NONE;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
08:16:23.0 (242543)|EXECUTION_STARTED
08:16:23.0 (259142)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0667xF000006oxVdf|VF: /apex/Invoicing
08:16:23.0 (13312753)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (13441311)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01px7F0000x0LkNyP|InvoicingController.InvoicingController()
08:16:23.0 (13458226)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|InvoicingController
08:16:23.0 (13605579)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (13770344)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (13856568)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (14154201)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (19599840)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (21998767)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[134]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_AttachId()
08:16:23.0 (22040027)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[134]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_AttachId()
08:16:23.0 (22087004)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[137]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap(Map<Id,String>)
08:16:23.0 (22103726)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[137]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap(Map<Id,String>)
08:16:23.0 (22112592)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[138]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoiceList()
08:16:23.0 (22122625)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[138]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoiceList()
08:16:23.0 (22189795)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[138]|List<Invoice__c>.size()
08:16:23.0 (22202267)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[138]|List<Invoice__c>.size()
08:16:23.0 (22248651)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_ENTRY|[139]|<init>(Integer)
08:16:23.0 (22280784)|SYSTEM_CONSTRUCTOR_EXIT|[139]|<init>(Integer)
08:16:23.0 (22304748)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[140]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoiceList()
08:16:23.0 (22330237)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[140]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoiceList()
08:16:23.0 (22346301)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[140]|List<Invoice__c>.iterator()
08:16:23.0 (22474025)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[140]|List<Invoice__c>.iterator()
08:16:23.0 (22498553)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22521036)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22624700)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[141]|Set<Id>.add(Object)
08:16:23.0 (22663304)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[141]|Set<Id>.add(Object)
08:16:23.0 (22674726)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[142]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (22685924)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[142]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (22715409)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[142]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (22729853)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[142]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (22738630)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22748831)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22770388)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[141]|Set<Id>.add(Object)
08:16:23.0 (22779678)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[141]|Set<Id>.add(Object)
08:16:23.0 (22785850)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[142]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (22791789)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[142]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (22804489)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[142]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (22826466)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[142]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (22833300)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22854234)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[140]|system.ListIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (22863836)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[145]|Set<Id>.size()
08:16:23.0 (22877083)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[145]|Set<Id>.size()
08:16:23.0 (24803336)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[146]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, parentId FROM Attachment 
08:16:23.0 (28930748)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[146]|Rows:2
08:16:23.0 (29023245)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[146]|Database.QueryLocator.iterator()
08:16:23.0 (29172496)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|QueryLocatorIterator.QueryLocatorIterator()
08:16:23.0 (29186945)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[7]|QueryLocatorIterator
08:16:23.0 (29376502)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[146]|Database.QueryLocator.iterator()
08:16:23.0 (29408348)|METHOD_ENTRY|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (29498555)|METHOD_EXIT|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (29512041)|METHOD_ENTRY|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
08:16:23.0 (29583621)|METHOD_EXIT|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
08:16:23.0 (29598561)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[147]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (29613987)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[147]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (29687170)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[147]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (29725618)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[147]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (29735629)|METHOD_ENTRY|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (29753927)|METHOD_EXIT|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (29760129)|METHOD_ENTRY|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
08:16:23.0 (29798424)|METHOD_EXIT|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.next()
08:16:23.0 (29807785)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[147]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (29813452)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[147]|InvoicingController.__sfdc_invoicePDFAttMap()
08:16:23.0 (29834644)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[147]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (29854927)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[147]|Map<Id,String>.put(Object, Object)
08:16:23.0 (29862649)|METHOD_ENTRY|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (29871409)|METHOD_EXIT|[146]||Database.QueryLocatorIterator.hasNext()
08:16:23.0 (38685737)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (38835424)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (38931168)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (38998425)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (39273616)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (39675353)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (47569436)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
08:16:23.0 (99101833)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/Invoicing
08:16:23.0 (99119007)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

1. How do I force stop this email trying to be sent?
2. How do I catch the error and display it to my visualforce page accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seems the issue is with the email service.
But the fact you adding lots of message with addMessage.

Instead you should concated your errors and add only 1 message.

e.g:

```
String errors = '';

for(Messaging.SendEmailError err : ser.getErrors()) {
        System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                    
        System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
        System.debug('fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
        errors +='Status Code: ' + err.getStatusCode() + ' Message: ' + err.getMessage() + ' Field Affected: ' + err.getFields();     
}

Apexpages.addMessage(new apexpages.message(Apexpages.Severity.Error, errors ));
```

Comment: You are totally wrong. I've commented out all the section under "//Catch invalid emails and expose to VF page" and the logs are still sending every 6 seconds

Comment: Then you probably have something else in the code that cause it. I tried myself writing simple page + controller which send email with wrong address and didn't notice this behavior.  Perhaps post your full code so people can have better look. + In addition, open those logs that you see in the debug and check what it is doing.

Comment: When I meant invalid emails. I mean like those emails like this: 
Your message wasn't delivered to <email> because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail. The response from the remote server was:
550 5.1.1 <email> User unknown.
Anyway have added debug log to my question

Comment: 1 thing seems obvious - the debug logs are not related to emails issue, because it different actions that runs. See for example line 146 query: "SELECT id, parentId FROM Attachment". Check where is this query and what might invoke it.
Generally, you will see 1 debug log for every time the page call to the server. If you see such calls without doing anything, possible you have polar or interval or the page listen to events. I'm not sure regarding the email errors but if it works for with other emails then probably issue is on the recipient email/server. Test it by email him outside salesforce

Comment: Yes I have emailed him outside salesforce using my Outlook account and the error message occurs "Your message wasn't delivered to <email> because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail. The response from the remote server was: 550 5.1.1 <email> User unknown". 
Is there anyway I can use Salesforce to catch this early and stop it?

Comment: I think you cannot, but you might need to consult with someone who better understand how email servers are working. Check if this link answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190746/how-to-handle-error-in-messaging-sendemail

Comment: Thanks for searching! Yeah the answer there makes sense - means it is not possible to capture the error.